# Trying to add an alert to detection model "ssd_mobilenet_v2", throws an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

Using "ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpn_keras" i am trying to add an alert system

The detection model is loaded in to the below function

```
 def detect_fn(image):
    image, shapes = detection_model.preprocess(image)
    prediction_dict = detection_model.predict(image, shapes)
    detections = detection_model.postprocess(prediction_dict, shapes)
    return detections
```

The image is converted to a tensor

```
input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
```

The the tensor is fead to the detection model

`detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)`

The output of the detection model is a dictionary, with the following keys:

```py
dict_keys(['detection_boxes', 'detection_scores', 'detection_classes', 'raw_detection_boxes', 'raw_detection_scores', 'detection_multiclass_scores', 'detection_anchor_indices', 'num_detections'])
```

`detections[detection_classes]`, gives the following output ie 0 is ClassA, 1 is ClassB

```
[0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

`detections['detection_scores']` gives the score for each box detected (a few shown below)

```
[0.988446 0.7998712 0.1579772 0.13801616 0.13227147 0.12731305 0.09515342 0.09203091 0.09191579 0.08860824 0.08313078 0.07684237
```

I am trying to `Print("Attention needed")`, if detection classB ie 1 is observed

```py
for key in detections['detection_classes']:
if key==1:
    print('Alert')
```

When i try to do that i get an error

```py
`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How do make it work?

I want the code to print "Attention needed" is Class =1 or A and detection_scores >= 14

[Code Explained, a bit further](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1wy8.jpg)

---

links for the complete code are below :

- [Tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqkISICHH-U&list=PLJkhWIudCqI0lo_AcuSlfIDpZhh4t5t3o&index=51&t=12325s)
- [GitHub sources repository](https://github.com/nicknochnack/TFODRPi)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the error message, you should use `.any()`. like:

```py
if (key == 1).any():
  print('Alert')
```

As `key == 1` will be an array with `[False, True, True, False, ...]`

You might also want to detect ones that exceeds certain score, say 0.7:

```py
for key, score in zip(
  detections['detection_classes'],
  detections['detection_scores']):
  if score > 0.7 and key == 1:
    print('Alert')
    break
```